# hibernate - many-to-one using addJoin

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a many-to-one relationship, where a MessageContents object has a set of Messages, and each Message has a foreign key to a MessageContents.

I have the following query:

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT " +
                  " {msg.*}, "+
                  " {msc.*} "+
                  "FROM analyticsintegrationservices.Messages AS msg " +
                  "LEFT OUTER JOIN analyticsintegrationservices.message_contents AS msc " +
                  " ON msg.content_key = msc.unique_key " +
                  "WHERE msg.sequence_received < 10";
```

When I query it , I want hibernate to map the result set to a list of Messages objects.
When I try the following code, I get a result set of MessageContents:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery( sqlQuery )
                    .addEntity( "msc", MessageContents.class )
                    .addJoin( "msg", "msc.message" )
                    .addJoin( "msc", "msg.messageContents" );
query.setResultTransformer( Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY );
//query.list() returns a list of MessageContents.
```

However, when I run the following code, I get the exception "org.hibernate.type.SetType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.EntityType"

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery( sqlQuery )
                     .addEntity( "msg",Messages.class )
                     .addJoin( "msc","msg.messageContents" )
                     .addJoin( "msg", "msc.message" );
query.setResultTransformer( Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY );
// org.hibernate.type.SetType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.EntityType
```

the esception occurs at the line

```
 .addJoin( "msg", "msc.message" );
```

How can I obtain a list of Messages with the sqlQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `sequence_received` id, or key-property, in you HBM file for the MessageContent? If it is, then why don't you use [session.load()](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) method, that will automatically take care of you childs and all,

and if that column is not your the key-property, then i will suggest you to use [Criteria](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html), that will properly, until your both the entities are related.

but these cases will help only in case when you have mapped both property in the HBM file properly.

Comment: I don't have a single HBM file. All my configuration is done via annotations. The      sequence_received is just a property, it's not the ID or key-property. Using Criteria is also out of the question for the company's policies (we don't want hibernate to generate any SQL code since we don't trust it with the code being optimal)

Comment: @iliaden : we u donot want to rely on hibernate on generating sql statements, then i will sugguest not to hibernate then.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your mappings are correct, you should do this:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery( sqlQuery )
                     .addEntity("msg", Messages.class )
                     .addJoin("msc", "msg.messageContents" ).
                     .addEntity("msg", Messages.class)
                     .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

List<MessageContents> yourList = query.list();
```

yourList will contain a list of MessageContents entities where the messageContents entities of the association are fully initialized.

The duplicate

```
            .addEntity("msg", Messages.class)
```

is necessary because

```
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

operates on the last entity added.

Answer (score 0):

You said that `MessageContents` will have set of messages, so I assume that `msc.message` is declared as set in your mapping. However, you declare `msg` as entity and you try to assign it to set. That causes the error. You should stick with your first declaration as `MessageContents` is your primary object.

By the way, error applies to your entire statement, not just last `.addJoin` it just happened to be the last line of it.

Comment: when I say what causes the exception, I mean that by removing that line, it compiles properly, but lacks the right mapping.  Also: is there a way to specify the type of class the results are mapped to anyways? I need a Messages as a primary object, not the MessageContents